# Azure: How to beste connect SQL-Database with MySQL/Webservice

Tags: mysql, api, azure, azure-sql-database

I am new to MS Azure just with some SQL Server Background and now we are facing some design / architecture questions and I am somehow lost.

One the one hand, there is a DataWarehouse and a small SQL-Database in Azure and they store all the structured or not structured incoming data. Works fine!

Now we think of moving the MySQL Database for the first version of the website (we need to stay at MySQL for the web-service) to Azure. In version two of the website, we like to integrate some of the Data from SQL-Database and DataWarehouse so it sounds good to have all the stuff at one place.

As much as possible from all the structured Data, we would like to store at the SQL-Database and not in MySQL. MySQL should stay lightweight. But what will be the beste way to create some interaction between Webservice, MySQL und SQL-Database?

Our Webdesigner asked for some APIs and as the users should be able to change some settings in their account we would need a lot of get and set APIs. And those APIs will just handle traffic within Azure, no external Access is needed. I just discovered the option of external Tables in Azure MySQL but cant find use-cases or best practice of that.

I am looking for a solution, in which I can deliver the necessary data for the Webdesigner / Frontend and they do not need to work with any databases (as they do not like to do that).

The traffic between MySQL and SQL-Database will be low (our stream goes into Datawarehouse, some analysis in there and we save the results as structured Data in the SQL-Database) and up to now we do not need a connection between Datawarehouse and MySQL/Webservice.

Any suggestions? How would you design such a connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Azure Data Factory you can maintain both databases and transfer (called as COPY in Data Factory) from SQL DB to Azure DB.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, you somehow answered my question by bringing Data Factory in my mind, I think, that will be the right tool, now I need to check it out in detail. Because COPY is not exactly what I am looking for, but I think some of the tubes will help me.

Comment: The copy activity will transfer the data from one source to other. You need 5 things here. 2 Linked services (basically connection string in simple language), 2 datasets (1 input and output), 1 pipeline incorporating the above 4.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but I think, I might look for something slightly different.

My Situation: I have all data of our customers stored in a SQL-Database, e.g. name, address, kind of their Login etc. And in Addition, I have an mySQL Server as a Backend of our website.

Comment: Now I would like to build up a fancy user-Management on the webpage: For each customer there should be a Master-User, (the CEO or the IT-Admin of a company) and this Master should be allowed to give specific access of his account to additional people (other employees of the same company - it will be a B2B service I am talking of).

Comment: Now, I do not like to copy any data from the SQL-Server to the mySQL server as then I need to store and maintain them at two places in the same time.

I still think about a design, in with I store all the information of the accounts and their rights in the SQL-Database (I constantly need this information in there as well), I link that table in the mySQL-Database and the user-Management of the webpage access this linked table within mySQL as if it is an ordinary table of mySQL.

Comment: And as the rights for such a user is given, the webpage may pull the requested data with a pipeline of Datafactory directly from the SQL-Server or I even linke the other necessary 

But I will not copy any data within this two databases, there should be just one version of each dataset and this two databases just should work together.

You helped me in bringing Datafactory back to my mind, but I think, I still need to figure our the best way to handle this case.